# improve for loop to paint in C# GDI

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi

I got a for loop which has to run 200,000 times calling graphics.DrawLine. This is very slow and I look forward for your help in increasing the performance of this loop. when I tried, Task Parallellism, it will give the error"The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this." I have also tried splitting the loop into two and execute them parallel, that also results in the same error. I have removed the code related to that attempts and have given the actual code which has to be optimized for performance.

The code is

// Take data from arraylist which is the data points for the graph

```
    Graphics g = null;
    public Drawing(Graphics _g, DrawingData _Data)
    {
        g = _g;
        drawingData = _Data;           
    }
    private void FrameDrawLine1()
    {
        DataValueSet pds = null;
        DataValueSet ds = null;

        for (int i = 1; i < drawingData.data.Count; i++) // the count will be 100,000
        {               
            ds = (DataValueSet)drawingData.data[i];                           
            PlotColumne(pds, ds);
        }                    
    }
```

// Get the color and other informtion about the graph parameters

```
    private void PlotColumne(DataValueSet pds, DataValueSet ds)
    {
        try
        {
            double totalSeconds = (drawingData.valueArea.maxDate - drawingData.valueArea.minDate).TotalSeconds;
            double xFrom = GetTimePixel(pds.time, totalSeconds);
            double xTo = GetTimePixel(ds.time, totalSeconds);
            PlotprintingDataset[] pt = initialisePlotprintingDataset();

            _referenceColumnindex++;
            PlotColumn column = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < drawingData.plotColumns.Count; i++) // this count will be around 50
            {
                column = (PlotColumn)drawingData.plotColumns[i];
                if (column.active)
                {
                    if (ValueIsNumber(Convert.ToDouble(ds.values[column.index]), Convert.ToDouble(pds.values[column.index])))
                    {
                        if (pt[column.index].X < -10000F)
                        {
                            pt[column.index].X = xFrom;
                            pt[column.index].Y = calculateYValueInGraph(column, Convert.ToDouble(pds.values[column.index]));
                        }

                        if (DrawLineInGraph(pds, ds,  column, pt))
                        {
                            pt[column.index].X = xTo;
                            pt[column.index].Y = calculateYValueInGraph(column, Convert.ToDouble(pds.values[column.index]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            GenericFunctions.ErrorMessage("Error has occured while plotting graph columns. Please try again.");
        }
    }
```

// Check if the point is in graph area and will call draw line method

```
    private bool DrawLineInGraph(DataValueSet pds, DataValueSet ds, PlotColumn column, PlotprintingDataset[] pt)
    {
        double totalSeconds = (drawingData.valueArea.maxDate - drawingData.valueArea.minDate).TotalSeconds;
        double xTo = GetTimePixel(ds.time, totalSeconds);
        double value = Convert.ToDouble(ds.values[column.index]);
        double y2 = calculateYValueInGraph(column, Convert.ToDouble(ds.values[column.index]));
        double y1 = calculateYValueInGraph(column, Convert.ToDouble(pds.values[column.index]));

        if (IsPointInPlausibleArea(pt, column, pds, ds))
        {
               drawLine(column.color, pt[column.index].X, xTo, pt[column.index].Y, y2, column.interpolate, column.lineWidth);

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

// Draw the lines in the graph

```
    private void drawLine(Color color, double xFrom, double xTo, double yFrom, double yTo,
        bool interpolate, int lineWidth)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Windows.Shapes.Line newline = new System.Windows.Shapes.Line();
            Pen linePen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(color), lineWidth);
            float x1 = (float)xFrom;
            float x2 = (float)xTo;
            float y1 = (float)yFrom;
            float y2 = (float)yTo;

            if (interpolate)
            {
                g.DrawLine(linePen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
            }
            else
            {
                g.DrawLine(linePen, x1, y1, x2, y1);
                g.DrawLine(linePen, x2, y1, x2, y2);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            GenericFunctions.ErrorMessage("Error has occured while drawing graph lines. Please try again.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Umm, you just start using `g` in `drawLine` where did it come from?

Comment: Don't compute when you are supposed to be drawing. Just do the computations once when the data they depend on changes, and then just draw a bunch of lines after that, based on the computations. You're not going to be able to parallelize the rendering part, because of the exception you ran into: if you're drawing to the screen, you have to do that drawing in the one UI thread. Even if you drew into an off-screen bitmap, the synchronization between the threads doing the drawing would be a big bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to draw to an image. To Do this you need to create your own Graphics Context from a Bitmap.

```
Bitmap yourBitmap = new Bitmap(your controls width, height, PixelFormat. Format32bppArgb)
GRAPHICS G = Graphics.FromImage(yourBitmap)
// Draw your lines here
```

finally you have to draw the picture with your original Graphics context to the control.
    e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(0,0, yourBitmap)

Additionally you can Tweak the parameters of the graphics Context. They have also a big influence on Performance.

Here a link to those parameters : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38262796/6439999